# Expected number of urns that are empty

Tags: probability

> We have $n$ balls that are numbered $1,...,n$ and are put into $n$
> urns also numbered 1 thru n in such way that ball $i$ is equally
> likely to go into any of the urns $1,2,...,n$. Find the expected
> number of urns that are empty. Also, find the probability that none of
> urns are empty.

### Attempt

Im confused as to how we place the balls into the urns. What is the convention in such problems? Because for instance, I don't know whether an urn can have at most one ball, or can hold more than one ball. This is my confusion, but my idea is to let $X$ be the number of empty urns and then define

$$ X_i = \begin{cases} 1, \; \; \; urn \; i \; empty \\ 0, \; \; \; otherwise \end{cases}$$

So that $X = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Now, since we want $E(X) $ and $E(X)= \sum^{n} E(X_i)$, then we just need to care about $E(X_i) = P(X_i=1)$. SO, in other words, the problem reduces to find the probability that the ith urn is empty.

### my Assumption: an urn can contain any number of balls

Assuming this, then the sample space is $n^n$ and the number of ways an urn is empty is just $n!$ since to have the ith urn empty all the other $n$ balls must go into remaining $n-1$ urns. Therefore $E(X_i) = \frac{n!}{n^n} $ and thus

$$ E(X) = n \frac{n!}{n^n} = \frac{n!}{n^{n-1} } $$

Now, if we want none of the urn empty, we just have to count in how many ways can all $n$ balls be placed in $n$ urns so that no urn is empty, well this is just $n!$. Threfore

$$ P(no \; urn \; empty) = \frac{n!}{n^n} $$

is my approach correct?

Comment: I believe that urns in probability problems usually have infinite capacity $\ddot\smile$

Comment: I don't get $E(X_i)$ as $n!/n^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard probability assumptions say that urns have unlimited capacity and/or balls have zero volume (wow!). Your ideas seem to be on the right track, although some of the calculations are off. $P(X_i = 1)$ is the probability that every single ball misses the $i$th bin. Each ball is independent and each is equally likely to land in every bin, so this is just $\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^n$. Then you would apply linearity of expectation in much the same manner as you do above.

The solution for the second problem seems fine.